# Redux store in WebWorker

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron

In many applications I have a background page. Such as with Electron, browser extensions. We can imagine it as the redux store being in a WebWorker.

I have components that need to be updated when the store updates. These components are not in the WebWorker, they are in various scopes that I can only send JSON strings to. What is the recommended way to send updates to these components?

I thought of doing store.subscribe in the webworker, and then send JSON.stringify of the store to all things connected. But then on the receving end, how do I update the store? There is no `store.replaceWholeStore(json)`. If there was, this would still not be a good solution, as all references changed, so it would trigger react to updated everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a variety of existing libraries and approaches for keeping Redux stores in sync. Most of them involve serializing actions and passing them across to other Redux stores for dispatching.

You may want to browse through the [Store#Synchronization](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#synchronization) and [Store#Interop](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store.md#integration-and-interop) sections of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) for a list of libraries that implement store synchronization approaches, including libs that specifically deal with Web Workers and Electron.  There's also some assorted articles that discuss this kind of idea, such as [Redux-Scuttlebutt: eventually consistent shared state between peers](https://medium.com/@grrowl/redux-scuttlebutt-eventually-consistent-shared-state-among-peers-191d48102079).

Comment: Thanks very much Markerikson I will take a look!